# How to sort first 10 ids in ascending order , then id = 11 - id = 20 in descending order followed by id = 21 to id = 30 in ascending order and so on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, object

I am making a board game using react. I am using an array of objects in the form

```
[
{ id : 1, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 2, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 3, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 4, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 5, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 6, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 7, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 8, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 9, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 10, tile : number, name : string},
{ id : 11, tile : number, name : string},
.
.
.
{ id : 100, tile : number, name : string},
]
```

I want to sort the id 1 -10 as ascending, 11 - 20 as descending, 21 - 30 as ascending 31 to 40 as desc, and so on.
i have tried multiple methods

1. splitting the entire array (having 100 objects) into groups of 10 and then applying sort (asc/desc) to them and finally using the concat() to get the final sorted array
2. using splice(0, 10).sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).map(value => value.id);
   //for first 10 ids
   spice(11, 20).sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).reverse().map(value => value.id);
   //for 11 - 20 ids and following the same pattern till 91 - 100.
3. putting conditions inside the sort itself (based on the units and tens place digits of the individual ids..)
   for eg :

   ```
   const Tiles = [
   {}, {}, {}, ..... {}, //100 objects with unique ids
   ]

   const sortTiles = Tiles.sort((a : any, b : any) => 
   parseInt(String(a.id).charAt(0) % 2 == 0)? 1 : -1); //for sorting 20s, 40s, 60s, 80s digits as ascending...
   ```

   but i want an optimal way of sorting the numbers as per the scheme I mentioned above.

   - 1 - 10 asc - left to right
   - 11 - 20 desc - left to right
   - 21 - 30 asc - left to right
   - 31 - 40 desc - left to right

     ... and so on.

here is my code - please suggest better solutions

```
 const Tiles = [
            {
                id: 1,
                tilenumber: 1,
                name: "start"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                tilenumber: 2,
                name: "two"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                tilenumber: 3,
                name: "three"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                tilenumber: 4,
                name: "four"
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                tilenumber: 5,
                name: "five"
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                tilenumber: 6,
                name: "six"
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                tilenumber: 7,
                name: "seven"
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                tilenumber: 8,
                name: "eight"
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                tilenumber: 9,
                name: "nine"
            },
            {
                id: 10,
                tilenumber: 10,
                name: "ten"
            },
            {
                id: 11,
                tilenumber: 11,
                name: "eleven"
            },
            {
                id: 12,
                tilenumber: 12,
                name: "tweleve"
            },
            {
                id: 13,
                tilenumber: 13,
                name: "thirteen"
            },
            {
                id: 14,
                tilenumber: 14,
                name: "fourten"
            },
            {
                id: 15,
                tilenumber: 15,
                name: "fifteen"
            },
            {
                id: 16,
                tilenumber: 16,
                name: "sixteen"
            },
            {
                id: 17,
                tilenumber: 17,
                name: "seventeen"
            },
            {
                id: 18,
                tilenumber: 18,
                name: "eighteen"
            },
            {
                id: 19,
                tilenumber: 19,
                name: "nineteen"
            },
            {
                id: 20,
                tilenumber: 20,
                name: "twenty"
            },
            {
                id: 21,
                tilenumber: 21,
                name: "twentyone"
            },
            {
                id: 22,
                tilenumber: 22,
                name: "twentytwo"
            },
            {
                id: 23,
                tilenumber: 23,
                name: "twentythree"
            },
            {
                id: 24,
                tilenumber: 24,
                name: "twentyfour"
            },
            {
                id: 25,
                tilenumber: 25,
                name: "twentyfive"
            },
            {
                id: 26,
                tilenumber: 26,
                name: "twentysix"
            },
            {
                id: 27,
                tilenumber: 27,
                name: "twentyseven"
            },
            {
                id: 28,
                tilenumber: 28,
                name: "twentyeight"
            },
            {
                id: 29,
                tilenumber: 29,
                name: "twentynine"
            },
            {
                id: 30,
                tilenumber: 30,
                name: "thirty"
            },
            {
                id: 31,
                tilenumber: 31,
                name: "thirtyone"
            },
            {
                id: 32,
                tilenumber: 32,
                name: "thirtytwo"
            },
            {
                id: 33,
                tilenumber: 33,
                name: "thirtythree"
            },
            {
                id: 34,
                tilenumber: 34,
                name: "thirtyfour"
            },
            {
                id: 35,
                tilenumber: 35,
                name: "thirtyfive"
            },
            {
                id: 36,
                tilenumber: 36,
                name: "thirtysix"
            },
            {
                id: 37,
                tilenumber: 37,
                name: "thirtyseven"
            },
            {
                id: 38,
                tilenumber: 38,
                name: "thirtyeight"
            },
            {
                id: 39,
                tilenumber: 39,
                name: "thirtynine"
            },
            {
                id: 40,
                tilenumber: 40,
                name: "fourty"
            },
            {
                id: 41,
                tilenumber: 41,
                name: "fourtyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 42,
                tilenumber: 42,
                name: "fourtyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 43,
                tilenumber: 43,
                name: "fourtyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 44,
                tilenumber: 44,
                name: "fourtyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 45,
                tilenumber: 45,
                name: "fourtyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 46,
                tilenumber: 46,
                name: "fourtySix"
            },
            {
                id: 47,
                tilenumber: 47,
                name: "fourtySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 48,
                tilenumber: 48,
                name: "fourtyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 49,
                tilenumber: 49,
                name: "fourtyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 50,
                tilenumber: 50,
                name: "fifty"
            },
            {
                id: 51,
                tilenumber: 51,
                name: "fiftyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 52,
                tilenumber: 52,
                name: "fiftyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 53,
                tilenumber: 53,
                name: "fiftyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 54,
                tilenumber: 54,
                name: "fiftyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 55,
                tilenumber: 55,
                name: "fiftyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 56,
                tilenumber: 56,
                name: "fiftySix"
            },
            {
                id: 57,
                tilenumber: 57,
                name: "fiftySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 58,
                tilenumber: 58,
                name: "fiftyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 59,
                tilenumber: 59,
                name: "fiftyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 60,
                tilenumber: 60,
                name: "Sixty"
            },
            {
                id: 61,
                tilenumber: 61,
                name: "sixtyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 62,
                tilenumber: 62,
                name: "sixtyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 63,
                tilenumber: 63,
                name: "sixtyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 64,
                tilenumber: 64,
                name: "sixtyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 65,
                tilenumber: 65,
                name: "sixtyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 66,
                tilenumber: 66,
                name: "sixtySix"
            },
            {
                id: 67,
                tilenumber: 67,
                name: "sixtySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 68,
                tilenumber: 68,
                name: "sixtyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 69,
                tilenumber: 69,
                name: "sixtyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 70,
                tilenumber: 70,
                name: "Seventy"
            }, {
                id: 71,
                tilenumber: 71,
                name: "seventyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 72,
                tilenumber: 72,
                name: "seventyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 73,
                tilenumber: 73,
                name: "seventyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 74,
                tilenumber: 74,
                name: "seventyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 75,
                tilenumber: 75,
                name: "seventyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 76,
                tilenumber: 76,
                name: "seventySix"
            },
            {
                id: 77,
                tilenumber: 77,
                name: "seventySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 78,
                tilenumber: 78,
                name: "seventyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 79,
                tilenumber: 79,
                name: "seventyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 80,
                tilenumber: 80,
                name: "Eighty"
            }, {
                id: 81,
                tilenumber: 81,
                name: "eightyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 82,
                tilenumber: 82,
                name: "eightyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 83,
                tilenumber: 83,
                name: "eightyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 84,
                tilenumber: 84,
                name: "eightyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 85,
                tilenumber: 85,
                name: "eightyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 86,
                tilenumber: 86,
                name: "eightSix"
            },
            {
                id: 87,
                tilenumber: 87,
                name: "eightySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 88,
                tilenumber: 88,
                name: "eightyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 89,
                tilenumber: 89,
                name: "eightyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 90,
                tilenumber: 90,
                name: "Ninety"
            }, {
                id: 91,
                tilenumber: 91,
                name: "ninetyOne"
            },
            {
                id: 92,
                tilenumber: 92,
                name: "ninetyTwo"
            },
            {
                id: 93,
                tilenumber: 93,
                name: "ninetyThree"
            },
            {
                id: 94,
                tilenumber: 94,
                name: "ninetyFour"
            },
            {
                id: 95,
                tilenumber: 95,
                name: "ninetyFive"
            },
            {
                id: 96,
                tilenumber: 96,
                name: "ninetySix"
            },
            {
                id: 97,
                tilenumber: 97,
                name: "ninetySeven"
            },
            {
                id: 98,
                tilenumber: 98,
                name: "ninetyEight"
            },
            {
                id: 99,
                tilenumber: 99,
                name: "ninetyNine"
            },
            {
                id: 100,
                tilenumber: 100,
                name: "Hundread"
            }
        ];
        
        /*var newSetTiles = Tiles.sort((a : any , b : any) =>
        parseInt(String(a.id).charAt(0))%2 == 0 || parseInt(String(a.id).charAt(1)) == 0 ? 1 : -1);
        console.log(newSetTiles, 'sorted'); */
        
        
         
        const tileSetA = Tiles.slice(0, 10).sort((a : any, b : any) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
    const tileSetB = Tiles.slice(11, 20).sort((a : any, b : any) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).reverse();
    const tileSetC = Tiles.slice(21, 30).sort((a : any, b : any) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
     
    const concatSet = tileSetA.concat(tileSetB);
    const concatSet_ = concatSet.concat(tileSetB);
       console.log(concatSet_);    
        
        export default concatSet_;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Create a loop for each slice, if even index just append it to new array, if odd reverse order then append it to new array.

```js
const Tiles = [{
    id: 1,
    tilenumber: 1,
    name: "start"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tilenumber: 2,
    name: "two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tilenumber: 3,
    name: "three"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    tilenumber: 4,
    name: "four"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    tilenumber: 5,
    name: "five"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    tilenumber: 6,
    name: "six"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    tilenumber: 7,
    name: "seven"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    tilenumber: 8,
    name: "eight"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    tilenumber: 9,
    name: "nine"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    tilenumber: 10,
    name: "ten"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    tilenumber: 11,
    name: "eleven"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    tilenumber: 12,
    name: "tweleve"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    tilenumber: 13,
    name: "thirteen"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    tilenumber: 14,
    name: "fourten"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    tilenumber: 15,
    name: "fifteen"
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    tilenumber: 16,
    name: "sixteen"
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    tilenumber: 17,
    name: "seventeen"
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    tilenumber: 18,
    name: "eighteen"
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    tilenumber: 19,
    name: "nineteen"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    tilenumber: 20,
    name: "twenty"
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    tilenumber: 21,
    name: "twentyone"
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    tilenumber: 22,
    name: "twentytwo"
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    tilenumber: 23,
    name: "twentythree"
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    tilenumber: 24,
    name: "twentyfour"
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    tilenumber: 25,
    name: "twentyfive"
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    tilenumber: 26,
    name: "twentysix"
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    tilenumber: 27,
    name: "twentyseven"
  },
  {
    id: 28,
    tilenumber: 28,
    name: "twentyeight"
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    tilenumber: 29,
    name: "twentynine"
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    tilenumber: 30,
    name: "thirty"
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    tilenumber: 31,
    name: "thirtyone"
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    tilenumber: 32,
    name: "thirtytwo"
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    tilenumber: 33,
    name: "thirtythree"
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    tilenumber: 34,
    name: "thirtyfour"
  },
  {
    id: 35,
    tilenumber: 35,
    name: "thirtyfive"
  },
  {
    id: 36,
    tilenumber: 36,
    name: "thirtysix"
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    tilenumber: 37,
    name: "thirtyseven"
  },
  {
    id: 38,
    tilenumber: 38,
    name: "thirtyeight"
  },
  {
    id: 39,
    tilenumber: 39,
    name: "thirtynine"
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    tilenumber: 40,
    name: "fourty"
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    tilenumber: 41,
    name: "fourtyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 42,
    tilenumber: 42,
    name: "fourtyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 43,
    tilenumber: 43,
    name: "fourtyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    tilenumber: 44,
    name: "fourtyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 45,
    tilenumber: 45,
    name: "fourtyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 46,
    tilenumber: 46,
    name: "fourtySix"
  },
  {
    id: 47,
    tilenumber: 47,
    name: "fourtySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 48,
    tilenumber: 48,
    name: "fourtyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 49,
    tilenumber: 49,
    name: "fourtyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 50,
    tilenumber: 50,
    name: "fifty"
  },
  {
    id: 51,
    tilenumber: 51,
    name: "fiftyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 52,
    tilenumber: 52,
    name: "fiftyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 53,
    tilenumber: 53,
    name: "fiftyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 54,
    tilenumber: 54,
    name: "fiftyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 55,
    tilenumber: 55,
    name: "fiftyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 56,
    tilenumber: 56,
    name: "fiftySix"
  },
  {
    id: 57,
    tilenumber: 57,
    name: "fiftySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 58,
    tilenumber: 58,
    name: "fiftyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 59,
    tilenumber: 59,
    name: "fiftyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 60,
    tilenumber: 60,
    name: "Sixty"
  },
  {
    id: 61,
    tilenumber: 61,
    name: "sixtyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 62,
    tilenumber: 62,
    name: "sixtyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 63,
    tilenumber: 63,
    name: "sixtyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 64,
    tilenumber: 64,
    name: "sixtyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 65,
    tilenumber: 65,
    name: "sixtyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    tilenumber: 66,
    name: "sixtySix"
  },
  {
    id: 67,
    tilenumber: 67,
    name: "sixtySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 68,
    tilenumber: 68,
    name: "sixtyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 69,
    tilenumber: 69,
    name: "sixtyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 70,
    tilenumber: 70,
    name: "Seventy"
  }, {
    id: 71,
    tilenumber: 71,
    name: "seventyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 72,
    tilenumber: 72,
    name: "seventyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 73,
    tilenumber: 73,
    name: "seventyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 74,
    tilenumber: 74,
    name: "seventyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 75,
    tilenumber: 75,
    name: "seventyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 76,
    tilenumber: 76,
    name: "seventySix"
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    tilenumber: 77,
    name: "seventySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 78,
    tilenumber: 78,
    name: "seventyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 79,
    tilenumber: 79,
    name: "seventyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 80,
    tilenumber: 80,
    name: "Eighty"
  }, {
    id: 81,
    tilenumber: 81,
    name: "eightyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    tilenumber: 82,
    name: "eightyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 83,
    tilenumber: 83,
    name: "eightyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 84,
    tilenumber: 84,
    name: "eightyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 85,
    tilenumber: 85,
    name: "eightyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 86,
    tilenumber: 86,
    name: "eightSix"
  },
  {
    id: 87,
    tilenumber: 87,
    name: "eightySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 88,
    tilenumber: 88,
    name: "eightyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 89,
    tilenumber: 89,
    name: "eightyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 90,
    tilenumber: 90,
    name: "Ninety"
  }, {
    id: 91,
    tilenumber: 91,
    name: "ninetyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 92,
    tilenumber: 92,
    name: "ninetyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 93,
    tilenumber: 93,
    name: "ninetyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 94,
    tilenumber: 94,
    name: "ninetyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 95,
    tilenumber: 95,
    name: "ninetyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 96,
    tilenumber: 96,
    name: "ninetySix"
  },
  {
    id: 97,
    tilenumber: 97,
    name: "ninetySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 98,
    tilenumber: 98,
    name: "ninetyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 99,
    tilenumber: 99,
    name: "ninetyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 100,
    tilenumber: 100,
    name: "Hundread"
  }
];


// First make sure they are in order, this may not be needed if you know they start in order
Tiles.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

let newArray = [];
const sections = Math.ceil(Tiles.length / 10)

for (let i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
  const slice = Tiles.slice(i * 10, i * 10 + 10);
  if (i % 2 === 1) {
    slice.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
  }
  newArray = newArray.concat(slice);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer here is a one-line solution:

```
const newArray = Array.from({length: Math.ceil(Tiles.length / 10)}, () => Tiles.splice(0, 10)).map((chunk, i) => i % 2 === 0 ? chunk : chunk.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)).flat()
```

See methods:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
const Tiles = [{
    id: 1,
    tilenumber: 1,
    name: "start"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tilenumber: 2,
    name: "two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tilenumber: 3,
    name: "three"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    tilenumber: 4,
    name: "four"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    tilenumber: 5,
    name: "five"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    tilenumber: 6,
    name: "six"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    tilenumber: 7,
    name: "seven"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    tilenumber: 8,
    name: "eight"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    tilenumber: 9,
    name: "nine"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    tilenumber: 10,
    name: "ten"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    tilenumber: 11,
    name: "eleven"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    tilenumber: 12,
    name: "tweleve"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    tilenumber: 13,
    name: "thirteen"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    tilenumber: 14,
    name: "fourten"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    tilenumber: 15,
    name: "fifteen"
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    tilenumber: 16,
    name: "sixteen"
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    tilenumber: 17,
    name: "seventeen"
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    tilenumber: 18,
    name: "eighteen"
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    tilenumber: 19,
    name: "nineteen"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    tilenumber: 20,
    name: "twenty"
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    tilenumber: 21,
    name: "twentyone"
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    tilenumber: 22,
    name: "twentytwo"
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    tilenumber: 23,
    name: "twentythree"
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    tilenumber: 24,
    name: "twentyfour"
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    tilenumber: 25,
    name: "twentyfive"
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    tilenumber: 26,
    name: "twentysix"
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    tilenumber: 27,
    name: "twentyseven"
  },
  {
    id: 28,
    tilenumber: 28,
    name: "twentyeight"
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    tilenumber: 29,
    name: "twentynine"
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    tilenumber: 30,
    name: "thirty"
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    tilenumber: 31,
    name: "thirtyone"
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    tilenumber: 32,
    name: "thirtytwo"
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    tilenumber: 33,
    name: "thirtythree"
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    tilenumber: 34,
    name: "thirtyfour"
  },
  {
    id: 35,
    tilenumber: 35,
    name: "thirtyfive"
  },
  {
    id: 36,
    tilenumber: 36,
    name: "thirtysix"
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    tilenumber: 37,
    name: "thirtyseven"
  },
  {
    id: 38,
    tilenumber: 38,
    name: "thirtyeight"
  },
  {
    id: 39,
    tilenumber: 39,
    name: "thirtynine"
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    tilenumber: 40,
    name: "fourty"
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    tilenumber: 41,
    name: "fourtyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 42,
    tilenumber: 42,
    name: "fourtyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 43,
    tilenumber: 43,
    name: "fourtyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    tilenumber: 44,
    name: "fourtyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 45,
    tilenumber: 45,
    name: "fourtyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 46,
    tilenumber: 46,
    name: "fourtySix"
  },
  {
    id: 47,
    tilenumber: 47,
    name: "fourtySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 48,
    tilenumber: 48,
    name: "fourtyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 49,
    tilenumber: 49,
    name: "fourtyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 50,
    tilenumber: 50,
    name: "fifty"
  },
  {
    id: 51,
    tilenumber: 51,
    name: "fiftyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 52,
    tilenumber: 52,
    name: "fiftyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 53,
    tilenumber: 53,
    name: "fiftyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 54,
    tilenumber: 54,
    name: "fiftyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 55,
    tilenumber: 55,
    name: "fiftyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 56,
    tilenumber: 56,
    name: "fiftySix"
  },
  {
    id: 57,
    tilenumber: 57,
    name: "fiftySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 58,
    tilenumber: 58,
    name: "fiftyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 59,
    tilenumber: 59,
    name: "fiftyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 60,
    tilenumber: 60,
    name: "Sixty"
  },
  {
    id: 61,
    tilenumber: 61,
    name: "sixtyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 62,
    tilenumber: 62,
    name: "sixtyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 63,
    tilenumber: 63,
    name: "sixtyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 64,
    tilenumber: 64,
    name: "sixtyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 65,
    tilenumber: 65,
    name: "sixtyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    tilenumber: 66,
    name: "sixtySix"
  },
  {
    id: 67,
    tilenumber: 67,
    name: "sixtySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 68,
    tilenumber: 68,
    name: "sixtyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 69,
    tilenumber: 69,
    name: "sixtyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 70,
    tilenumber: 70,
    name: "Seventy"
  }, {
    id: 71,
    tilenumber: 71,
    name: "seventyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 72,
    tilenumber: 72,
    name: "seventyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 73,
    tilenumber: 73,
    name: "seventyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 74,
    tilenumber: 74,
    name: "seventyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 75,
    tilenumber: 75,
    name: "seventyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 76,
    tilenumber: 76,
    name: "seventySix"
  },
  {
    id: 77,
    tilenumber: 77,
    name: "seventySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 78,
    tilenumber: 78,
    name: "seventyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 79,
    tilenumber: 79,
    name: "seventyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 80,
    tilenumber: 80,
    name: "Eighty"
  }, {
    id: 81,
    tilenumber: 81,
    name: "eightyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    tilenumber: 82,
    name: "eightyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 83,
    tilenumber: 83,
    name: "eightyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 84,
    tilenumber: 84,
    name: "eightyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 85,
    tilenumber: 85,
    name: "eightyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 86,
    tilenumber: 86,
    name: "eightSix"
  },
  {
    id: 87,
    tilenumber: 87,
    name: "eightySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 88,
    tilenumber: 88,
    name: "eightyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 89,
    tilenumber: 89,
    name: "eightyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 90,
    tilenumber: 90,
    name: "Ninety"
  }, {
    id: 91,
    tilenumber: 91,
    name: "ninetyOne"
  },
  {
    id: 92,
    tilenumber: 92,
    name: "ninetyTwo"
  },
  {
    id: 93,
    tilenumber: 93,
    name: "ninetyThree"
  },
  {
    id: 94,
    tilenumber: 94,
    name: "ninetyFour"
  },
  {
    id: 95,
    tilenumber: 95,
    name: "ninetyFive"
  },
  {
    id: 96,
    tilenumber: 96,
    name: "ninetySix"
  },
  {
    id: 97,
    tilenumber: 97,
    name: "ninetySeven"
  },
  {
    id: 98,
    tilenumber: 98,
    name: "ninetyEight"
  },
  {
    id: 99,
    tilenumber: 99,
    name: "ninetyNine"
  },
  {
    id: 100,
    tilenumber: 100,
    name: "Hundread"
  }
];


// First make sure they are in order, this may not be needed if you know they start in order
Tiles.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);


const newArray = Array.from({
  length: Math.ceil(Tiles.length / 10)
}, () => Tiles.splice(0, 10)).map((chunk, i) => i % 2 === 0 ? chunk : chunk.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)).flat()

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother : ). You just saved me and cleared my concept of sorting things effectively as well. Not only this, I got to know the efficient usage of slice(), and math.ceil() - methods as well.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to "accept" this answer there's a check mark button you can click.